# Continuous function taking each of its values twice

Tags: real-analysis

I read that a continuous function can't take each of it's values exactly twice.
But I don't understand why e.g. take the function $x^2$ and add one point to it very close to $0$ that also has $0$ value (and shift the rest of the function with the difference between the $x$-coordinate of the added point and $0$), then it takes each value twice. Or is it not continuous in this case?

Also could you give me a function in R that takes each of its values three times?

Comment: Every function that satisfies this property has an infinite number of discontinuities. Refer to http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-02/S0002-9939-1986-0854049-8/S0002-9939-1986-0854049-8.pdf

Comment: But how does mine have an infinite number of them? It has only one shift in it.

Comment: What is this point that's very close to $0$?  I think that if you actually try to define the function rigorously, you will see that your approach will not create a precisely $1$-to-$2$ function.

Comment: Where are you adding the point? What does the function do between the new point and 0?  You can't just shift it along like that in a well defined way.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Doesn't that require compactness of domain or something?  Otherwise $f(x) = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, defined on $[0, 2)$, takes on each value exactly twice.

Comment: @BrianTung That example is discontinuous. $|x|$ on $\mathbb R - 0$ is cts and 2-1. Further, $f:[0,1]\cup[2,3]\to \mathbb R$ with $f:x\mapsto x$ on $[0,1]$ and $f:x\mapsto x-2$ on $[2,3]$ is 2-1 on a compact, but disconnected domain.

Comment: @Ori: I know it's discontinuous.  It does not have an *infinite* number of discontinuities.  Your second example is well taken, though.  Connected and compact, then?

Comment: It seems I am misunderstanding something in regards to the claim from the paper as all examples that come to mind have a finite amount of discontinuities.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of functions which take each their values three times are

$$f(x)=\cot\left(\frac{3\pi}{1+\exp(-x)}\right)$$

as well as

$$f(x)=2\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3\pi}\right\rfloor-\cos\left(3\pi\left\{\frac{x}{3\pi}\right\}\right).$$